# How to turn on progress bar if jquery post starts to take too long

Tags: ajax, jquery

Is it possible to only show some kind of progress after a jquery ajax post starts to take too long, but not bother showing it if fairly instantaneous?  I have the following code that uses a setTimeout to delay showing my progress indicator (it's basically a twitter bootstrap modal that I enable and it has a progress indicator gif in it), but it appears to not work when I am debugging and put a brek point on my server side code, which then, in my client-side setTimeout, it should go off, but the setTimeout is never called until my server returns a response (so I never get the progress bar then if taking too long).  It works fine when I don't use setTimeout to delay it (basically not delaying at all), or if I do such a short delay that the progress indicator shows up almost instantaneously, but not with the 1.5 sec delay.

Here is my javascript:

```
var progressModalRunning = false;
var needModalProgress = true;

// document.ready events/functions to call
$(function () {
    $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
        if (!form.valid || form.valid()) {
            toggleModalProgressAndButtons(form, true);

            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serializeArray())
                .done(function (json) {
                    json = json || {};

                    // In case of success, we redirect to the provided URL or the same page.
                    if (json.success) {
                        location = json.redirect || location.href;
                    } else if (json.errors) {
                        displayErrors(form, json.errors);
                        toggleModalProgressAndButtons(form, false);
                    }
                })
                .error(function () {
                    displayErrors(form, ['An unknown error happened.']);
                    toggleModalProgressAndButtons(form, false);
                });
        }
    });
});

// show/hide modal progress indicator and disable/enable modal buttons
var toggleModalProgressAndButtons = function (form, toggle) {
        if (toggle) {
            showProgress();
        } else {
            hideProgress();
        }
}

// display validation errors
var displayErrors = function (form, errors) {
    needModalProgress = false;

    var errorSummary = getValidationSummaryErrors(form)
        .removeClass('validation-summary-valid')
        .addClass('validation-summary-errors');

    var items = $.map(errors, function (error) {
        return '<li>' + error + '</li>';
    }).join('');

    var ul = errorSummary
        .find('ul')
        .empty()
        .append(items);
};

// Show a progress indicator in it's own modal
var showProgress = function () {
    // we will delay it by 1.5 seconds - don't want to bother showing if the response is that     fast,
    // because it makes the screen to appear to flicker since backdrop for modal is darker
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (needModalProgress) {
            progressModalRunning = true;

            $('#progress').modal({ keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' });
    }
    }, 1500);
}

// hide the progress indicator
var hideProgress = function () {
    if (progressModalRunning) {
        progressModalRunning = false;
        needModalProgress = true;

        $('#progress').modal('hide');
    }
}
```